# Javascript/jQuery - Parallax effect on divs containing content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a parallax effect on divs on click on an element. I have html set up like this:

```
<div id="app">

    <div id="main-section">
      <top-bar></top-bar>

      <div id="main-content">
        ...

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="item-detail">
    </div>

  </div>
```

I have an image slider in `main-content` div, and on click of an image slider div `item-detail` is being populated with content, on the page load is empty. Now I would like to somehow get the parallax effect of when the div is populated, that it scrolls to the top-bar and goes over the `main-content` div.

I have tried with something like this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#item-detail").offset().top
}, 1700);

parallaxScroll();

function parallaxScroll(){
    var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('#item-detail').css('top','-' + ((scrolledY*1.3)) + 'px');
}
```

And the css for the divs:

```
#main-section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 900px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('/img/cover.png');
  background-size: cover;
}

#main-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 77px;
  height: 833px;
}

#item-detail {
  position: absolute;
  top: 900px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

But it didn't work for me, and both `main-content` and `item-detail` have `top` set to `0` after the function was executed on click.